Unexpected behavour: interletter spacing when using sansmathfonts
Consider the following MWE, which employs the beamer document class. The spacing between "d" and "f" in the numerator and between "d" and "t" in the denominator looks fine when the default sans serif math font (Computer/Latin Modern Sans, right?) is in use.

\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{dt}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

But if I add the instruction \usepackage{sansmathfonts}, the space between "d" and "f" nearly vanishes, while it increases needlessly between "d" and "t".

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{dt}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

Unfortunately, I have to use sansmathfonts. How can I set it up to get the correct spacing?

Nothing to do with beamer, you'd get the same spacing with \documentclass{article} \usepackage{sansmathfonts} \begin{document} \[\frac{df}{dt}\] \end{document}

For people who are fine with switching to LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX, New Computer Modern provides a Sans Math font, with complete unicode math coverage. https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern

The creator of the sansmathfonts package may need to spend some more time improving the kerning among all-lowercase letter pairs. (I haven't examined the situation for uppercase-lowercase or all-uppercase letter pairs.)
For instance, let's examine the situation for letter pairs that involve just the first 13 letters of the Latin alphabet. The first screenshot shows the kerning if beamer's default sans serif math font (Computer Modern Math) is in use. The second screenshot repeats the kerning table, but now with sansmathfonts loaded; I've added highlighting for the pairs where, in my opinion, kerning really needs to be improved.
With Computer Modern Sans:

With SansMathFonts:

The upshot? I suggest you contact the package's author and ask if the kerning tables could be adjusted.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\midrule' macro
%\usepackage{sansmathfonts} % uncomment as needed
\usepackage{array}  % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{calc}   % for '\widthof' macro

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}

$
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{@{} l @{\quad} *{13}{wc{\widthof{mm}}} @{}}

% create contents of 'array' programatically, via some Lua 'for' loops
\directlua{

ll = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m"} 
% -- first, print the header row
for k=1,13 do
  tex.sprint ( "&"..ll[k] )
end
tex.sprint ("\\\\ \\midrule")
% -- now the 14 x 13 matrix
for i=1,13 do
  tex.sprint (ll[i])
  for j=1,13 do
    tex.sprint ( "&"..ll[i]..ll[j] )
  end
  tex.sprint ("\\\\")
end

}
\end{array}
$

\end{frame}
\end{document}

